# How to show Google Slide Presentation while seeing the notes on other computer?

Tags: google-slides

I have created a Google Slide with lots of notes on every slide.

I am showing the presentation from a computer connected to a projector.

I want to see the notes on an other computer. I want that when I change slide, I will see the next slide notes.

Do you have any idea how should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

It is can be solved exactly like other question:
[How to show PowerPoint presentation while seeing the notes on other computer?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25789/how-to-show-powerpoint-presentation-while-seeing-the-notes-on-other-computer/25816#25816)

In Google slide, I click present with notes. I am moving the notes window to the fake monitor. and connect the second computer to the fake monitor.

Hope it is helps.